# Error when installing cabal package (cannot determine mingw version)

Tags: haskell, mingw, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I would like to install a package using cabal, but I get this error:

```
Warning: cannot determine version of D:\Program Files\Haskell
Platform\8.0.2\mingw\bin\gcc.exe :
""
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: -1073741502)
```

The package is `stm`:

```
cabal install stm
```

I've installed the full x64 version of `Haskell Platform` on my Windows 10 PC.

The error is almost the same as here: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4442

But that is not answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win10 Creators Update changed some APIs that ghc was affected by. You may be seeing the result of this. If you have Win 10 build 15019 or later replace your gcc.exe as detailed at the [ghc-compat repo](https://github.com/Mistuke/ghc-compat) as see if that helps.